# Add a subquery to SELECT statement that depends on the first column?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, correlated-subquery

Is there a way I can write this query in a way to get the result of my sub query compared with my `category_id`.

```
SELECT category_id,
count(id) as TOTAL COUNT, 
(select count(*) from products where product_path LIKE '%Electronics%'
 and category_id = category_id ) as ELECTRONIC COUNT
FROM products
WHERE product_path LIKE '%Products%'
GROUP BY category_id
```

I want the Results in the bellow manner:

```
"category_id"   "TOTAL COUNT"   "ELECTRONIC COUNT"
   "173"              "1"               "243"
    "42"              "1"               "243"
   "211"              "41"              "243"
   "162"              "10"              "243"
   "172"              "139"             "243"
   "116"              "54"              "243"
    "10"              "3"               "243"
```

I want the electronic count to be dependent on category. I.e., first row should be where `category_id = 173`, 2nd one where `category_id = 42`, 3rd should be where `category_id = 211` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your **correlated subquery** work with the same table, you would have to use [**table aliases**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM):

```sql
SELECT category_id
      ,count(*) AS total_count  -- unquoted column alias with space is wrong, too
      ,(SELECT count(*)
        FROM   products AS p1
        WHERE  product_path LIKE '%Electronics%'
        AND    p1.category_id = p.category_id
       ) AS electronic_count
FROM   products AS p
WHERE  product_path LIKE '%Products%'
GROUP  BY category_id;
```

Assuming `id` is the primary key and, as such, `NOT NULL`. Then `count(*)` does a better job.

But this can be further **simplified** to:

```sql
SELECT category_id
      ,count(*) AS total_count -- keyword AS is needed for column alias
      ,count(product_path LIKE '%Electronics%' OR NULL) AS electronic_count
FROM   products p  -- keyword AS is just noise for table alias
WHERE  product_path LIKE '%Products%'
GROUP  BY category_id;
```

Much faster.
`count()` only counts non-null values. By adding `OR NULL` I convert `FALSE` to `NULL`. Thereby only those rows count, where `product_path LIKE '%Electronics%'` evaluates to `TRUE`.